# React number format first number overwrite default value

Tags: react-number-format

I'm using react-number-format decimal amount. How do I make sure that default value is zero, but when a user enters the first number, (say 1 for example) it results in the total input value being 1 and not 10. So, the default 0 is removed.

Could be me, but I would expect the formatter to work this way. Is there a native way of doing this, or do I implement this logic myself?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am also running into this exact same issue. You describe it well.

Comment: Haven't yet found time to address it, pls let me know your approach if you address it first.